# require or include Relative path

Tags: php

I reading some code, and i have question.

In file path : `/home/project/projects/func.php`

```
require_once('include/somePhpCode.php');
```

`include/somePhpCode.php` that in require_once, in `/home/project/projects/include/`

it simple, but in file path : `/home/project/projects/func.php` (same file)

```
require_once('DB.php')
```

it is not `/home/project/projects/DB.php` but `/home/project/projects/pear/DB.php/`.

what is difference?

In `php.ini`:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
;
; PHP's default setting for include_path is ".;/path/to/php/pear"
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

; The root of the PHP pages, used only if nonempty.
; if PHP was not compiled with FORCE_REDIRECT, you SHOULD set doc_root
; if you are running php as a CGI under any web server (other than IIS)
; see documentation for security issues.  The alternate is to use the
; cgi.force_redirect configuration below
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.doc-root
doc_root =

; The directory under which PHP opens the script using /~username used only
; if nonempty.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.user-dir
user_dir =
```

These are default values.

How to find PHP DB.php, is not same directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the correct `php.ini`? You might have different versions for CLI and Apache.

Comment: Because if you're finding the include file in `/home/project/projects/pear`, there must be a `php.ini` that adds that to `include_path`.

Comment: thank you reply, i reconfirm php.ini, that is......

Comment: require_once('pear/DB.php')